Steel Frame Broke (Top Tube Just Behind Head Tube)
I have a 1992 Trek 950 Mountain Bike.  I've converted it into a cargo bike with racks and baskets;  I ride it day or night, rain or shine.  I have about 50,000 miles on it.  Over the past month or so I've noticed that it was getting a bit noodly in the handling.  Yesterday when arriving home I bumped up the curb into the driveway and noticed that the top tube just behind the head tube was completely broken all the way around.  The break was just at the point of the lug.  The bottom of the top tube was a bit rounded, so it had been bouncing there for a while.... I really like this bike.   So, Can I get it welded?  Or brazed?  How much should I expect to pay?  Any thoughts appreciated.  Thank you.

Alas,  I failed to take any photos before I welded it.  Yes,  I'm a welder.  I am looking for other peoples opinions about this project so I didn't volunteer that fact in the initial post.  TIA for any thoughts.  I have to figure out how to post photos.  In the meantime, a bit of the bike's history. This bike was a gift to me, so I don't have any paperwork on it.  The fellow who gave it to me had only a hundred or so miles on it.  He was coasting down a hill and approaching a signalized intersection.  The motorist on the side street "didn't see him" and ran the light.  The bicyclist ran into the side of the car just at the front wheel.  He was going at a decent clip and flew up onto the hood of the car.  He planted his hands on the hood and did a flip over the car and landed running on the street on the other side of the car(!)  The motorist stopped.  The bike wasn't run over, the bicyclist wasn't hurt.  The motorist apologized and departed.  The bicyclist rode home and put the bike in the garage.  He decided that God had sent him a message and never rode a bike again. After a month or so, he gave it to me.  I did not check the down tube before my top tube broke, but it (the down tube) has a wrinkle on the bottom side.  It is maybe 1/16" or so.  I'm willing to assume that the breaking of the top tube and the wrinkle on the bottom tube are related.  I'll get to work on figuring out how to attach photos.  Thank you for your concern for my continued well-being.

Just out of curiosity, in https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/95720/10595 you say you're a welder and give a price estimate for a different repair. Why this question?

Could you add photos please?

It's a fairly old bike, but if you bought it new I'd see if you can dig up your original warranty.  Trek used to (they may still, but I don't know) give a lifetime warranty on their steel frames, and if you can dig up any documentation on the original purchase you might be able to get them to replace it for you.
(Source:  Trek warrantied my 2003 Trek 520 frame when the down tube cracked after a comparable amount of total use; >70Mm in my case.  I took the bike in and they gave it back to me with a new frame.  The only cost to me was a replacement FD that had welded itself to the frame and didn't come off intact.)
